How to calculate $y$ value from the given data
How do you come up with a formula to calculate the $y$ value based on the data given on the graph image below?
As you can see, the highest $y$ value is $2$, and the $x$ value is $13.5$ which is the middle point between $7$ and $20$.
What is the $y$ value when $x=10$?
What is the $y$ value when $x=18$?

Here's my attempt to calculate the y-axis.  It's almost correct.
double xpoint = 9.0; //xpoint can be any number between 7 and 20
double ypos = 0.0;
double minx = 7.0;
double maxx = 20.0;
double maxy = 2.0;

double rangex = maxx - minx;
double middlex = rangex / 2;
double yunit = maxy / middlex;
double middlexTime = middlex + minx;

double yposAdjustment = 0.3;

if (xpoint > middlexTime) {
  ypos = (maxx - xpoint).abs() * yunit + yposAdjustment;
} else {
  ypos = (minx - xpoint).abs() * yunit + yposAdjustment;
}


Why a formula? Looks like you are expected to use your eyes, a pen and a ruler.
